# Возможен ли breakpoint на определённых данных в Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, breakpoint

Интересует вопрос о том, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы брейкпоинты срабатывали только на определённом участке кода, при прохождении определённых данных? К примеру, есть лист с пятью миллионами элементов, каждая итерация вызывает стороннюю функцию к элементу, мне нужно, чтобы брейкпоинт сработал, к примеру, на 4-ых тысячном элементе, чтобы не пробегать по всем. Актуально для Intellij Idea 2016.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Правый клик по breakpoint, в поле `Condition` напишите нужное вам условие (напр. `i == 400`).
Для открытия более детальной настройки ваших breakpoints:

`Ctrl+Shift+F8` - Windows

`⇧⌘F8` - Mac

Comment: премного благодарен!